# Saving dataframe and additional data in same .csv file with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, save

**Description**: I have a set of parameters (`par1`, `par2`, `par3`, `par4`) and a dataframe `df`. In this example the parameters and the number of columns of the dataframe are respectively  are 4 and 3 but they could both be a generic number.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# list of parameters
par1 = 1.05
par2 = 20
par3 = 50000
par4 = 12315468

# Dataframe
dic = {'A' : ['PINCO','PALLO','TOLLO','FINGO','VOLVA'],
       'B' : [ 4     , 5     , np.nan, 1     , 0],
       'C' : [ 1     , 4     , 8     , 7     , 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

**My goal** is to save this data in the same *.csv* file but I don't know how to do it since the number of parameters doesn't match the number of columns of `df`.

My output file must should follow this rule:

- first row: list of parameters
- second row and after: content of dataframe

Therefore it looks like this:

[image]

**Question**: Could you provide a smart and efficient way to obtain the output file with the desired shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create list of parameters `par1`, `par2`, `par3`, etc,.

`l = [par1, par2, par3, par4]`

Then save the list to csv

```
filename = 'abc.csv'
pd.DataFrame(l).T.to_csv(filename, index=False, header=False)
```

Use python's append mode to append the data frame to csv.

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:  # Use append mode.
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first create list of parameters `pars`, then overwrite columns by `pars` with same `length` and last use `reindex`, but values has to be `unique`:

```
# list of parameters
par1 = 1.05
par2 = 20
par3 = 50000
par4 = 12315468

pars = [par1,par2,par3,par4]

# Dataframe
dic = {'A' : ['PINCO','PALLO','TOLLO','FINGO','VOLVA'],
       'B' : [ 4     , 5     , np.nan, 1     , 0],
       'C' : [ 1     , 4     , 8     , 7     , 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df.columns = pars[:len(pars) - 1]
print (df)
  1.05      20.00     50000.00
0    PINCO       4.0         1
1    PALLO       5.0         4
2    TOLLO       NaN         8
3    FINGO       1.0         7
4    VOLVA       0.0         6

df = df.reindex(columns=pars)
print (df)
  1.05         20.00        50000.00     12315468.00
0       PINCO          4.0            1          NaN
1       PALLO          5.0            4          NaN
2       TOLLO          NaN            8          NaN
3       FINGO          1.0            7          NaN
4       VOLVA          0.0            6          NaN
```

Another possible solution is use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of `DataFrame` created from list `pars`:

```
pars = [par1,par2,par3,par4]

# Dataframe
dic = {'A' : ['PINCO','PALLO','TOLLO','FINGO','VOLVA'],
       'B' : [ 4     , 5     , np.nan, 1     , 0],
       'C' : [ 1     , 4     , 8     , 7     , 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print (df)

df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
s = pd.DataFrame([pars])
print (s)
      0   1      2         3
0  1.05  20  50000  12315468

df1 = pd.concat([s, df], ignore_index=True)
print (df1)
       0     1      2           3
0   1.05  20.0  50000  12315468.0
1  PINCO   4.0      1         NaN
2  PALLO   5.0      4         NaN
3  TOLLO   NaN      8         NaN
4  FINGO   1.0      7         NaN
5  VOLVA   0.0      6         NaN
```

EDIT Also is possible use mode `a` for append in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
filename = 'filename.csv'
pars = [par1,par2,par3,par4]
pd.DataFrame([pars]).to_csv(filename, index=False, header=False)
df.to_csv(filename, index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

Comment: I think he/she does not want `NaN` on the last column. Is that possible ? I mean can the header be of different size than that of the data ?

Comment: Hmmm, answer is not.

Comment: Is it possible to use the second method by somehow telling the concat function to ignore the column names and therefore skipping the df.columns option?

Comment: I think not, because `concat` align data by `columns`

Comment: I changed some values of the parameters and while creating the dataframe s, I get a single column instead of the row... do you know how this is possible?

Comment: You forget `[]` in `s = pd.DataFrame([pars])`

Comment: I modify and simplify another solution, please check it.